# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.technivance.q84sale.base.controller.listener.DownloadFileUIListener"

Tags: android

I have an application and once I run it on device it crashes.

here is the crash report:

```
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/technivance/q84sale/base/controller/listener/DownloadFileUIListener;
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1086)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2809)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2988)
at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap14(ActivityThread.java)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1631)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6682)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1520)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1410)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.technivance.q84sale.base.controller.listener.DownloadFileUIListener" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.forsale.forsale-1/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.forsale.forsale-1/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.forsale.forsale-1/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.forsale.forsale-1/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.forsale.forsale-1/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.forsale.forsale-1/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.forsale.forsale-1/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.forsale.forsale-1/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.forsale.forsale-1/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.forsale.forsale-1/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.forsale.forsale-1/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.forsale.forsale-1/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.forsale.forsale-1/lib/arm, /system/fake-libs, /data/app/com.forsale.forsale-1/base.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /data/app/com.forsale.forsale-1/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /data/app/com.forsale.forsale-1/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /data/app/com.forsale.forsale-1/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /data/app/com.forsale.forsale-1/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /data/app/com.forsale.forsale-1/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /data/app/com.forsale.forsale-1/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /data/app/com.forsale.forsale-1/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /data/app/com.forsale.forsale-1/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /data/app/com.forsale.forsale-1/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /data/app/com.forsale.forsale-1/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /data/app/com.forsale.forsale-1/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:380)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
... 12 more
```

can any one tell me what is the problem as I could not understand the error ?

Comment: Have you tried, Cache Invalidate and Rebuild Project then unistall App from device and reinstall?

Comment: How are you running on device, through external apk(as in from drive or somewhere)?